# Creating a machine image that can work on 2 machines with different graphics cards

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, disk-image

**My scenario:**

- I have two different Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machines.
- Both have NVidia GPUs.
- Both are Tesla cards with different architectures and require
  different drivers.
- Both have all drivers installed and working
  properly using a debian package.

**My question:**

Is there a way to create a single image containing both sets of drivers? If so, how would I point the machine to the correct driver, or would I need to at all?